# How to show a form if a particular radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, radio-button

I want to show a particular form when a radio button is selected.
The code seems to work for me fine except for that when the page loads it shows both the forms instead of one form whose value is checked in the input tag

```
<?php
function print_form()
{
$newform = "
<body>
<section>
<div><strong>Select your Quantity Format</strong></div>

    <input type=\"radio\" id=\"radio1\" name=\"radios\" value=\"radio1\" checked onclick=\"show()\">
    <label for=\"radio1\">Per Unit</label>

    <input type=\"radio\" id=\"radio2\" name=\"radiOS\" value=\"radio2\" onclick=\"show()\">
    <label for=\"radio2\">Per Box</label>

<form method=\"post\" id=\"unit\" action=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}\" >
<table border=1 cellpadding=3 cellspacing=3 width='30%'>
<tr>
<th colspan=2 align='left' bgcolor='#EAEAEA'>Add Medicine/Item Details</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Medicine/Item Name</td>
<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"Medicine/Item_Name\"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Company Name</td>
<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"Company_Name\"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Stowage Rack No.</td>
<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"Rack\" onkeypress=\"return isNumberKey(event)\" ></td>
</tr>   
<tr><td colspan=2><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Add Record\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"true\" name=\"unit\"></td></tr>
</table></form>

<form method=\"post\" id=\"box\" action=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}\" >
<table border=1 cellpadding=3 cellspacing=3 width='30%'>
<tr>
<th colspan=2 align='left' bgcolor='#EAEAEA'>Add Medicine/Item Details</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Medicine/Item Name</td>
<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"Medicine/Item_Name\"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Company Name</td>
<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"Company_Name\"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Minimum Stock (Boxes)</td>
<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"Minimum_Stock_box\" onkeypress=\"return isNumberKey(event)\"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Stowage Rack No.</td>
<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"Rack\" onkeypress=\"return isNumberKey(event)\" ></td>
</tr>       
<tr><td colspan=2><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Add Record\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"true\" name=\"box\"></td></tr>
</table></form>

</section>
<body>
";

return $newform;    
}


if(isset($_POST['unit']))
{
save_record_unit();
}

else if(isset($_POST['box']))
{
save_record_box();
}
else
{
print print_form();
}
?>
```

The JavaScript I used for this is as below

```
function show()
{       
var radios = document.getElementsByName("radios");
var unit =  document.getElementById("unit");
var box =  document.getElementById("box");

        box.style.display = 'block';
for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {

 radios[i].onclick = function() {
    var val = this.value;
    if(val == 'radio1' ){
        unit.style.display = 'block';
        box.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if(val == 'radio2'){
         unit.style.display = 'none';
         box.style.display = 'block';
    }    

  }
 }
}
```

Comment: If you want a radio button to pull information from the Server, you should use AJAX. If you already know what the form will look like depending on the selected radio, you can do this all with JavaScript.

Comment: @PHPglue I know how the form will look like and I am using JavaScript but the problem is that once the page loads both forms appear instead of one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here it is with your php function :

```js
function show()
{   
var radios = document.getElementsByName("radios");
var unit =  document.getElementById("unit");
var box =  document.getElementById("box");

        box.style.display = 'none';
for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {

 radios[i].onclick = function() {
    var val = this.value;
    if(val == 'radio1' ){
        unit.style.display = 'block';
        box.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if(val == 'radio2'){
         unit.style.display = 'none';
         box.style.display = 'block';
    }    

  }
 }
}
```

```css
.alert{ color:white; background-color:red;padding:2em;margin:2em;}
```

```html
<body>
  <?php
function print_form(){
$newform="
<section>
<div><strong>Select your Quantity Format</strong></div>

    <input type=\"radio\" id=\"radio1\" name=\"radios\" value=\"radio1\"  onclick=\"show();\" checked>
    <label for=\"radio1\">Per Unit</label>

    <input type=\"radio\" id=\"radio2\" name=\"radios\" value=\"radio2\" onclick=\"show();\">
    <label for=\"radio2\">Per Box</label>

<form method=\"post\" id=\"unit\" action=\"\" >
<table border=1 cellpadding=3 cellspacing=3 width='30%'>
<tr>
<th colspan=2 align='left' bgcolor='#EAEAEA'>Add Medicine/Item Details</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Medicine/Item Name</td>
<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"Medicine/Item_Name\"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Company Name</td>
<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"Company_Name\"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Stowage Rack No.</td>
<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"Rack\" onkeypress=\"return isNumberKey(event);\" ></td>
</tr>   
<tr><td colspan=2><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Add Record\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"true\" name=\"unit\"></td></tr>
</table></form>
    
<form method=\"post\" id=\"box\" action=\"\" >
<table border=1 cellpadding=3 cellspacing=3 width='30%'>
<tr>
<th colspan=2 align='left' bgcolor='#EAEAEA'>Add Medicine/Item Details</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Medicine/Item Name</td>
<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"Medicine/Item_Name\"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Company Name</td>
<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"Company_Name\"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Minimum Stock (Boxes)</td>
<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"Minimum_Stock_box\" onkeypress=\"return isNumberKey(event);\"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Stowage Rack No.</td>
<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"Rack\" onkeypress=\"return isNumberKey(event);\" ></td>
</tr>       
<tr><td colspan=2><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Add Record\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"true\" name=\"box\"></td></tr>
</table></form>

</section>
<script> show();</script>";
return $newform;
}



if(isset($_POST['unit']))
{
    //save_record_unit();
    echo "<div class=\"alert\">save_record_unit</div>";
}

else if(isset($_POST['box']))
{
    //save_record_box();
    echo "<div class=\"alert\">save_record_box</div>";
}
else
{
print print_form();
}
?>
</body>
```

i have placed `<script> show();</script>` at the end of the function print_form() for it to be executed by javascript each time the function is called by php

Answer (score 1):

it seems you forgot to hide one at the first beginning. You can do it directly in the html with `style='display:none'` or in a css class or directly with jquery at the load of the page.

Comment: I have changed the script but it is still showing both forms.                                                                                                                                                                 `//rest of the script same                                                                                         unit.style.display = 'none'; // I think this was missing 
 box.style.display = 'block';

for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
 //rest of the script same as previous`

Comment: you have an error in name='radiOS' for the id='radio2'

Comment: I never tried not to display a form, it's the first time i see this. If it doesn't work, create a div that will wrap your form and give it the id of the form.
one div id="unit" and one div id="box", and it should work.

Comment: Also the body tag is not closed at the end.

Comment: name='radiOS' error is just a type mistake as well as the body tag. I have checked the original code and div is also not working.

Comment: First correct name='radiOS', close the body tag, AND please correct this in your javascript: 'box.style.display' should be 'none' instead of 'block' juste before the for loop. I did test on my computer and everything is ok: only unit form at the beginning and the change of form as you press the radios buttons.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but I have corrected the name='radiOS' and closed the body tag also I have changed the box.style.display to none as well but still not getting the required results.

Answer (score 0):

ok check my test, you will see it works, feel free to look at the source code:
[your test page](http://diromain.free.fr/test/tt.html)
or here

```js
function show()
{   
var radios = document.getElementsByName("radios");
var unit =  document.getElementById("unit");
var box =  document.getElementById("box");

        box.style.display = 'none';
for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {

 radios[i].onclick = function() {
    var val = this.value;
    if(val == 'radio1' ){
        unit.style.display = 'block';
        box.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if(val == 'radio2'){
         unit.style.display = 'none';
         box.style.display = 'block';
    }    

  }
 }
}
show();//to start hidding box
```

```html
<section>
<div><strong>Select your Quantity Format</strong></div>

    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radios" value="radio1"  onclick="show();" checked>
    <label for="radio1">Per Unit</label>

    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radios" value="radio2" onclick="show();">
    <label for="radio2">Per Box</label>

<form method="post" id="unit" action="" >
<table border=1 cellpadding=3 cellspacing=3 width='30%'>
<tr>
<th colspan=2 align='left' bgcolor='#EAEAEA'>Add Medicine/Item Details</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Medicine/Item Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Medicine/Item_Name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Company Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Company_Name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Stowage Rack No.</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Rack" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" ></td>
</tr>   
<tr><td colspan=2><input type="submit" value="Add Record">
    <input type="hidden" value="true" name="unit"></td></tr>
</table></form>
    
<form method="post" id="box" action="" >
<table border=1 cellpadding=3 cellspacing=3 width='30%'>
<tr>
<th colspan=2 align='left' bgcolor='#EAEAEA'>Add Medicine/Item Details</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Medicine/Item Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Medicine/Item_Name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Company Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Company_Name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Minimum Stock (Boxes)</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Minimum_Stock_box" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Stowage Rack No.</td>
<td><input type="text" name="Rack" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event);" ></td>
</tr>       
<tr><td colspan=2><input type="submit" value="Add Record">
    <input type="hidden" value="true" name="box"></td></tr>
</table></form>

</section>
```

Comment: Your's is working perfectly but you know I have save these forms in a variable and then into a function, the function is been then called.

Comment: right but the function return the same. Just place this code in your function, write your php variables, and you will see that it's ok.
If you have corrected name='radios' in id radio2, turn box.style.display to none in your javascript, and at the end of the javascript the show() order for the first call, then, it will be ok. Edit your code, and i'll try it on my server side.

Comment: Thanks alot that `<script> show();</script>`trick did the work.